# Sanitizing input with C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to sanitize my input for a SQLite database and I'm using `sqlite3_mprintf` to do it, but I'm getting some weird results. I tried different variations, am I doing something wrong?

```
const char * zChar = "It's a nice day";
cout << sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('%Q')", zChar) << endl;
//INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES(''It''s a nice day'')

cout << sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES(%Q)", zChar) << endl;
//INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('It''s a nice day')

cout << sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('%q')", zChar) << endl;
//INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('It''s a nice day')

cout << sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES(%q)", zChar) << endl;
//INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES(It''s a nice day)
```

Comment: Seems to be working exactly as they should: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html
What were you expecting?

Comment: Also, note that you should free the memory returned with `sqlite3_free()`

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for pointing that out, forgot about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES(%Q)", zChar)
//INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('It''s a nice day')

sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('%q')", zChar)
//INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('It''s a nice day')
```

These are both correct. `''` is an escaped quote. The `%Q` option just adds the surrounding quotes itself.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that an escaped quote would have a backslash before it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html), that is expected behavior. The documentation also states that:

> As a general rule you should always use %q instead of %s when
>   inserting text into a string literal.